# Filtering an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, traversal

I have the following li element:

```
<li>
    <span><img src="../media/check.svg" class="complete"></span>
    <span><img src="../media/modify.svg" class="modify"></span>
    <span><img src="../media/delete.png" class="delete"></span>
    <span class="dutyText">hello</span>
<li>
```

When an image is clicked (check.svg|modify.svg|delete.png), I want to get the last span element of the above list.

Unfortunately, with the following code, I get undefined:

```
console.log($(this).closest('li').filter('.dutyText').html());
```

The questions that I have are:

1. How can I take the last element using jQuery?
2. Is there anyway to use the filter function and if not why?
3. Why I get undefined?

Answer (score 5):

1. How can I take the last element using jQuery?

   > You can use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector or [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) method on the jQuery collection
2. Is there anyway to use the filter function and if not why?

   > You can use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) as follow. However, in this case, you don't need filter.

   ```
   $(this).closest('li').children().filter('.dummyText')
   ```
3. Why I get undefined?

   > `$(this).closest('li').filter('.dutyText')` will search for the closest ancestor `<li>` and will try to get the `li` having `dummyText` class from it. As the closest `li` don't have class `dummyText`, the selector will not select any element and so calling `html()` on empty object returns `undefined`.

**Assuming there is only one element with class `dummyText`**

1. As the element is the sibling of the `img`, you can use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

   ```
   $(this).siblings('.dutyText')
   ```
2. You can also use parent-child hierarchy

   ```
   $(this).closest('li').find('.dutyText')
   ```

**Multiple elements having `dummyText` class**

1. You can use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector to get the last element.

   ```
   $(this).closest('li').find('.dutyText:last')
   ```
2. You can use [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) method

   ```
   $(this).closest('li').find('.dutyText').last()
   ```

Comment: Welcome @lampropoi. If you think this answer the question and is the best answer please accept the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

1 : When you want the last element from a collection use `.last()`.

2 : `filter()` is meant to filter a collection of JQuery elements. In your case you want to select one depth deeper (children). So you need to do `find()`.

3 : You get undefined because you're trying to get the HTML from an `li` with the class `.dutyText`. And it did not exists.